# Where can I learn to use Pig without having to set up Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My goal is to learn Pig in order to enhance my resume for machine learning/statistical analysis jobs. I am not really interested in all of the nitty gritty Hadoop details at the moment (although I would love to learn them later-it has just been very difficult to set up on my machine even with instructions, I'm more a stats guy than a programmer).  Is there some resource where I could learn Pig, and have easy access to it to for
experimentation, without having to learn Hadoop from the ground up?

Comment: Just a thought, you might be able to learn Hive quicker than pig because it uses a SQL like syntax (assuming you know SQL)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Install pig and then run it locally. It can do everything locally (albeit in most cases more slowly) that it can do over hadoop.

For the interactive shell (grunt):

```
pig -x local
```

To run a pig script locally:

```
pig -x local some_script.pig
```

The best docs on how to use pig are over at [Apache](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/), and they've got a [pretty good tutorial](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/start.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on [Cloudera QuickStartVM](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/DemoVMs/Cloudera-QuickStart-VM/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html), which includes a ready to use Pig environment.